# MxGraph JavaScript: How to calculate edge length?

Tags: javascript, function, edges, mxgraph

I am looking for a way to calculate the length of the edges in one graph.
As an example this image:
[The connecting edge contains three parts, (a,b and c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvh7a.png)
I have no idea how to retrieve this information that I can sum up the distances of a + b + c.

On a more complexe graph I want to calculate the length for each edge. There I would loop through all models of the graph, check with .isEdge if it is an edge and then calculate the length of each edge.

```
let cells = graph.getModel().cells;
            
for(let key in cells){
    let mxCell = cells[key];
    if(mxCell.isEdge())
        {
            calcLength(mxCell)
        } }
```

calcLength() is the function I need. This one should return the length of the edge.

I used the [helloPorts](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/helloport.html) example from jGraph.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand. But it is more a problem what to look for. Thus I have no code to illustrate it but I tried to explain the problem more in detail.

Comment: What is your input (data structure)? Can you give sample input in JavaScript syntax? And then add what the expected results would be for that input?

Comment: I added a short code snippet to illustrate how I want to access the data and where I want to use the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back again,

together with a friend we found the solution. The information is stored under the graphView in the state as the length.

```
graphView.getState(mxCell).length
```

This is part of the [mxCell](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxCell-js.html) object. If you are looking for the Euclidian length of an edge, this is stored under terminalDistance.

```
graphView.getState(edge).terminalDistance
```

The code would look like this to access it:

```
                let cells = graph.getModel().cells;
                let graphView = graph.getView();
                
                
                // The getModel needs to be triggered before the loop otherwise the the mxCell state is undefined
                graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                
                for(let key in cells){
                    let mxCell = cells[key];
                    if(mxCell.isEdge())
                    {
                        let state = graphView.getState(mxCell).length;
                    }
                    
                }
```